# Conditioning a String

Tags: java, conditional-statements, poker

Quick question. I'm wondering how I can make this so that it will only run when a number from 2-23 is entered by the user.

```
         BufferedReader in;
         int x;
         String playerx;

         //user input for number of players
         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         System.out.println("\nWelcome to the Casino!");
         System.out.println("How many players are playing? (2-23)");
         //string for number of players
         playerx = in.readLine(); 
         //convert players to integer
         x = Integer.valueOf(playerx).intValue(); 

         //condition player x so that the number of players are between 2 and 23
         if(playerx.compareTo("1")==0 && playerx.compareTo("24")==0) {
            System.out.println("\nSorry, there are either not enough players or not enough cards for that option.");
        }else {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
  if( x< 2 ||  x >  23) {
            System.out.println("\nSorry, there are either not enough players or not enough cards for that option.");
   }else {
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already have `int` value for number of players i.e `x`,  so better that for comparison to keep things simple.

Change this :

```
     if(playerx.compareTo("1")==0 && playerx.compareTo("24")==0) {
```

to

```
     if(x > 1 && x > 24) {
```

Comment: But I want x to be more than 1 and less than 24. They can't equal 1 or 24 either. Would this work?

`if(x <= 1 && x >= 24) {`

Comment: @ZackMortimer the condition is for x greater than 1 and less than 24 only (exluding both 1 and 24)